# Backbone.js Model different url for create and update?

Tags: rest, backbone.js

lets say I have a Backbone Model and I create an instance of a model like this:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
var John = new User({ name : 'John', age : 33 });
```

I wonder if it is possible when I use `John.save()` to target `/user/create` when I use `John.save()` on second time (update/PUT) to target `/user/update` when I use `John.fetch()` to target `/user/get` and when I use `John.remove()` to target `/user/remove`

I know that I could define `John.url` each time before I trigger any method but I'm wondering if it could be happen automatically some how without overriding any Backbone method.

I know that I could use one url like `/user/handle` and handle the request based on request method (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) but I'm just wondering if there is a way to have different url per action in Backbone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Methods [`.fetch()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-40), [`.save()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41) and [`.destroy()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-42) on `Backbone.Model` are checking if the model has `.sync()` defined and if yes it will get called otherwise `Backbone.sync()` will get called (see the last lines of the linked source code).

So one of the solutions is to implement `.sync()` method.

**Example:**

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({

  // ...

  methodToURL: {
    'read': '/user/get',
    'create': '/user/create',
    'update': '/user/update',
    'delete': '/user/remove'
  },

  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

    return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good solution.  Instead of `options = options || {};`, you should be using `options || (options = {});` to avoid the unnecessary reassignment.

Comment: @BrianNickel I agree that your code is more optimized but I'm a bit reserved to include it in the answer because JSLint/JSHint tools are marking it as a problem and in my opinion it is bit harder to read ... but I gave you +1 because it deservers an attention :).

Comment: Thanks a lot dzejkej for pointing out that it will first look the sync method of model, I missed that completely :) Thanks @Brian Nickel for pointing this out too :)

Comment: @dzejkej, make sure you return the result value from sync (otherwise this breaks deferred invocation pattern) sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
  }

Comment: Great solution! Learnt this detail.

Comment: what is the arguments parameter passed into the last function?

Comment: [@dzejkej](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011582/dzejkej) You can suppress the JSHint error by putting this above: `/* jshint -W030 */`

Comment: @ChrisMcJava [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), or you can use `call(method, model, options)`.

Answer (score 2):

To abstract *dzejkej's* solution one level further, you might wrap the `Backbone.sync` function to query the model for *method-specific URLs*.

```
function setDefaultUrlOptionByMethod(syncFunc)
    return function sync (method, model, options) {
        options = options  || {};
        if (!options.url)
            options.url = _.result(model, method + 'Url'); // Let Backbone.sync handle model.url fallback value
        return syncFunc.call(this, method, model, options);
    }
}
```

Then you could define the model with:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: setDefaultUrlOptionByMethod(Backbone.sync),
    readUrl: '/user/get',
    createUrl: '/user/create',
    updateUrl: '/user/update',
    deleteUrl: '/user/delete'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you dealing with a REST implementation that isn't to spec or needs some kind of workaround?

Instead, consider using the `emulateHTTP` option found here:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Otherwise, you'll probably just need to override the default `Backbone.sync` method and you'll be good to go if you want to get real crazy with that... but I don't suggest that.  It'd be best to just use a true RESTful interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I'll take in consideration of following the REST implementation instead of "hacking around" :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this by default with backbone. What you could to is to add to the model that will change the model url on every event the model trigger. But then you have always the problem that bckbone will use `POST` add the first time the model was saved and `PUT` for every call afterward. So you need to override the `save()` method or `Backbone.sync` as well.

After all it seems not a good idea to do this cause it break the `REST` pattern Backbone is build on.

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by [this](https://github.com/alexanderscott/backbone-login/blob/master/public/models/SessionModel.js) solution, where you just create your own ajax call for the methods that are not for fetching the model. Here is a trimmed down version of it:

```
var Backbone = require("backbone");
var $ = require("jquery");
var _ = require("underscore");

function _request(url, method, data, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: method,
    data:  JSON.stringify( data ),
    success: function (response) {
      if ( !response.error ) {
        if ( callback && _.isFunction(callback.success) ) {
          callback.success(response);
        }
      } else {
        if ( callback && _.isFunction(callback.error) ) {
          callback.error(response);
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(mod, response){
      if ( callback && _.isFunction(callback.error) ) {
        callback.error(response);
      }
    }
  });
}

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "login", "logout", "signup");
  },

  login: function (data, callback) {
    _request("api/auth/login", "POST", data, callback);
  },

  logout: function (callback) {
    if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
      _request("api/auth/logout", "GET", null, callback);
    }
  },

  signup: function (data, callback) {
    _request(url, "POST", data, callback);
  },

  url: "api/auth/user"

});

module.exports = User;
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var user = new User();

// user signup
user.signup(data, {
  success: function (response) {
    // signup success
  }
});

// user login
user.login(data, {
  success: function (response) {
    // login success
  }
});

// user logout
user.login({
  success: function (response) {
    // logout success
  }
});

// fetch user details
user.fetch({
  success: function () {
    // logged in, go to home
    window.location.hash = "";
  },
  error: function () {
    // logged out, go to signin
    window.location.hash = "signin";
  }
});
```