# backbone overriding url for collection create

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to change the URL that gets loaded when create() is called on a collection? I am doing it on models as noted here: 
[Backbone.js Model different url for create and update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731729/backbone-js-model-different-url-for-create-and-update)

Here is an example of my collection code:

```
var GroupsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Group,
    url:"/api/groups/get_all/",
    parse:function(res){                    
        return res.groups;
    },

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var methodUrl = {
            'add': '/api/group/create/'
        };
        if (methodUrl && methodUrl[method.toLowerCase()]) {
            options = options || {};
            options.url = methodUrl[method.toLowerCase()];
        }
        Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }    
});
```

I coped the sync function from my model class (Group). I am using the key 'add' in methodUrl because the Backbone documentation says an "add" event is triggered when create() is called. I've tried "create" instead of "add" as well (doesn't work).

Calling create() always just loads the url: "/api/groups/get_all"

Help? Open to any ideas about best practices around this stuff too. Thanks!

Comment: Have you overriden the create url of the Group model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it might be easier to read if you could folow the rest "convention" and let Backbone handle your URL with it's default. (It's pretty easy to switch on request.method in most servers).

Anyway, you could simply change the URL at creation time :

```
 groupCollection.create(
   {attr1: 'val1', etc: '...'}, 
   {url: '/api/group/create/'}
 ).save()
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm going with. The other option I was thinking was to keep the URL very generic (/api/group/) and pass in the action ("create") as a parameter. Either way, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Read the `backbone.js` source, you will find that: `Collection.sync` is only invoked by  `Collection.fetch` .  So your override doesn't work.  You should override  `Model.sync` in your `Group` model.

Comment: Is there any way to change the url that gets called when Collection.create() is called?

Comment: Override the `Group.sync` method. Or for a  global, override the `Backbone.sync`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend sticking with your original approach of overriding `Backbone.sync`. It sounds like the reason what you had didn't work is because you've set the url once in the collection and once in the model. You only need to -- and should -- set the url in *either* the model *or* the collection. If that wasn't the reason it didn't work, it definitely didn't work because backbone's 'add' method is called `create`. From the source:

```
var methodMap = {
  'create': 'POST',
  'update': 'PUT',
  'delete': 'DELETE',
  'read':   'GET'
};
```

A few simplifications to your sync override:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});

    if (method === 'create') {
        options.url = '/api/group/create/';
    }

    Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
```

None of the above really addresses the source of your problem though: Your server should be routing the request based on the HTTP verb. For example if you're `POST`ing, your server should route to an method that takes the incoming parameters and creates a new object from them. That will allow you set a generic `/api/groups/` url on your Backbone collection, regardless of whether you're creating, reading, updating, or destroying.