# Custom URL for Create, Update and Delete in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have requirement like [backbone-js-model-different-url-for-create-and-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731729/backbone-js-model-different-url-for-create-and-update/8733071#8733071), but didn't get anything working out of it.

I have my Backbone Model as this:-

```
var task = backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "TaskId",

    defaults: {
        TaskId: null,
        Name: null,
        TaskTypeId: null
    },

    // urlRoot: '/MyController/GetTasksAsync',
    methodToURL: {
        'read': '/MyController/Get',
        'create': '/MyController/create',
        'update': '/MyController/update',
        'delete': '/MyController/remove'
    },
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

        return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Now, I am not getting how to call the `Sync` method?

This is what I tried but didn't work:-

```
this.model.sync("read",1,"");//(Get method, some hardcoded value /Get/1,no callback)
```

I similar lines how will I call the save method?

```
this.model.sync('update',model,'');
```

Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're actually looking for are the Backbone Model methods fetch, save, and destroy which delegate to the sync method that you have overridden.

Here are the docs for fetch (save and destroy are nearby):

[model.fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)

For example, to trigger the 'read' method you could call model.fetch().

Comment: More specifically, you could declare a model (var model = new task()) and then perform model.save() to hit the 'create' path (if the model is new; the 'update' path otherwise), model.fetch() to hit the 'read' path and model.destroy() to hit the 'delete' path.

Comment: Additionally, these methods allow an object to be passed in (options in the docs) which gets mapped to the options parameter in the sync method.  You could, if you so desire, add the id in there (1 in your example) and check for that property of the object in the sync method.  If it's there you could concatenate it to the end of the uri....

Comment: I have seen the docs, and if i follow the docs I couldn't get it work. Can you post in with some proper syntax?>

Comment: Using the code you provided, you could declare a model like so:

var taskModel = new task();

Now, in order to hit sync with the ‘read’ method you would do:

taskModel.fetch();

You should see a GET request in the console to /MyController/Get.  You might want to preface that path with a server address.

If you wanted to go to /MyController/Get/{id} when you do taskModel.fetch() you could rewrite that options.url line to be something like this:

options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()] + (model.get(‘TaskId’) === null ? ‘’ : ‘/‘ + model.get(‘TaskId’));